# Preg_replace - regular expression - PHP "autolink"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, autolink

I have a piece of code that turn single words or phrases into clickable internal links from a given list.
Code is supposed to do this action only if the word or phrase is not linked yet.
It is working very great actually except for one point:
Code is considering name from src images attribute.

So,

```
<img src="img/xiaomi.jpg" />
```

is outputting

```
<img src="img/<a href="site.com/tag/xiaomi">Xiaomi</a>.jpg" />
```

As you can see probably regex is too greedy and getting what is not to get.

Code is modified to simplicity but is used as follows:

```
$content     = 'All post content itself with all html tags a site can have. <p>Blabla</p> <img src="img/xiaomi.jpg" /> <p>Bliblibli</p> <p>Lorem ipsum xiaomi</p>';
$contentCopy = 'All post content itself with all html tags a site can have. <p>Blabla</p> <img src="img/xiaomi.jpg" /> <p>Bliblibli</p> <p>Lorem ipsum xiaomi</p>';

$list = $this->cache->get('wordsList');

foreach($list as $word){
    $var = $word->word;
    $text = preg_replace('/<a[\S\s]+?<\/a>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b'.$var.'\b/i', '<a href="'.base_url('site/tag/'.url_title($var)).'" target="_blank" title="'.ucfirst($var).'">$0</a>', $text);
}
$content = str_replace($contentCopy,$text,$content);
```

Can you guys please help to improve this code?

Apparently the problem is only in image tags.

I use this snippet to auto create internal links for stored pages and help on site SEO

Comment: Add `img` to the SKIP-FAIL part.

Comment: Wouldn't this count for all attributes of any markup?

Comment: how does that SKIP/FAIL part work?

Comment: this pulls the images `.+(\<img.+\/\>).+`

Comment: I mean replace `<a[\S\s]+?<\/a>` with `(?:<a[\S\s]+?<\/a>|<img\b[^>]*>)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. I have tested now and code works. If you want to you can write an answer so I can accept as solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace `<a[\S\s]+?<\/a>` with `(?:<a[\S\s]+?<\/a>|<img\b[^>]*>)`. Here is a variation with a `.` and `s` modifier instead of `[\s\S]`:

```
'~(?:<a.*?</a>|<img\b[^>]*>)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\b'.$var.'\b~si'
```

Quick details:

- `(?:<a.*?</a>|<img\b[^>]*>)` - `<a`, any 0+ chars as few as possible, `</a>`, or `<img`, word boundary, any 0+ chars other than `>` and then `>`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` - PCRE verbs that make the current match fail at the current index and start the next match search from this index where failure occurred
- `|` - or
- `\b...\b` - whole word `$var` (only works if it contains just word chars, else you need to `preg_quote($var, "~")` and use other boundaries).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Uez2g/1).